# Ignite cache transaction rolled back

Tags: ignite

I executed below transaction code.

```
        Ignite ignite = IgniteClientPool.getClient();
        CacheConfiguration<String, Annotations> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
        cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        cfg.setName("myCache");
        IgniteCache<String, Annotations> annotationCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
        IgniteTransactions transactions = ignite.transactions();
        try (Transaction tx = transactions.txStart()) {
            LOG.info("Transaction started ");
            String key = requestDTO.getKey();
            Annotations annotation = annotationCache.get(key);
            annotation.setType(requestDTO.getType());
            annotationCache.put(key, annotation);
            if (requestDTO.getType() == 78) {
                throw new Exception("Exception thrown");
            }
            tx.commit();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Transaction failed ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Expected behavior - When type is equal to 78, Transaction should fail and type is not set to 78 in ignite db.

Actual behavior - When type is equal to 78, Exception is thrown and type is set to 78.
Rollback is not happening when exception is thrown. I tried explicitly calling tx.rollback() and behavior was same.

How can I enable transaction here?

Comment: I agree with your expects. Are you sure that the previous Anotations.getType() value is not 78?

Comment: Are you sure that "myCache" were initially created as `TRANSACTIONAL` cache?

Comment: Yes. I found the reason. It wasn't initially created in transaction mode. Here I was trying to modify the atomicity mode of existing cache. We cannot modify the configuration after creating the cache.